# iPhone animation options

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I am moving a UIImageView with the following animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{
                     myImage.frame = CGRectOffset(myImage.frame, myImageOffset.x, myImageOffset.y);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }
 ];
```

The problem is the image starts moving slow, then speeds up and slows down again before ending the animation.  Isn't the UIViewAnimationCurveLinear option supposed to make the animation perform at a constant rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this option instead - `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear`.  I found it while looking at this question on another site - http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/89009-block-animation-ignores-uiviewanimationcurvelinear.html